# MySQL SELECT COUNT with multiple fileds

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have following data in `MySQL` table.

```
+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
| AcctStartTime       | UserName                  |    ResponseCode |
+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+
| 2014-12-01 16:24:34 | 10000018@example.com |             408 |
| 2014-12-01 16:48:36 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-01 17:24:09 | 10000018@example.com |             408 |
| 2014-12-01 17:45:41 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-01 17:53:43 | 10000018@example.com |             408 |
| 2014-12-01 18:08:51 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-01 18:50:19 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-01 23:21:50 | 10000018@example.com |             502 |
| 2014-12-01 23:22:14 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
| 2014-12-01 23:26:14 | 10000018@example.com |             484 |
| 2014-12-01 23:29:31 | 10000018@example.com |             408 |
| 2014-12-01 23:30:36 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
| 2014-12-01 23:39:57 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
| 2014-12-01 23:42:55 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-01 23:57:58 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 00:25:28 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 00:28:28 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 00:47:36 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 01:32:07 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 01:36:49 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 01:55:15 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 01:56:43 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 01:58:16 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
| 2014-12-02 02:33:09 | 10000018@example.com |             484 |
| 2014-12-02 02:37:30 | 10000018@example.com |             408 |
| 2014-12-02 02:40:53 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
| 2014-12-02 02:42:07 | 10000018@example.com |             484 |
| 2014-12-02 02:44:31 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 02:49:35 | 10000018@example.com |             408 |
| 2014-12-02 02:50:36 | 10000018@example.com |             408 |
| 2014-12-02 02:51:52 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 03:18:18 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
| 2014-12-02 03:38:54 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 03:42:00 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 03:49:13 | 10000018@example.com |             200 |
| 2014-12-02 04:00:41 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
| 2014-12-02 04:03:18 | 10000018@example.com |             487 |
```

I want to find out every day how many `ResponsCode` count we get per day, just like following, i don't know how do i use `GROUP` condition here, i tired many option but i didn't get desired output.

```
+---------------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|      date           |       200     |    503    |    487   |
+---------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------
| 2014-12-01          |         5     |      3    |      7   |     
| 2014-12-02          |         8     |      1    |      2   |     
| 2014-12-03          |         4     |      0    |      9   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get just a touch creative for this, with `SUM` in a `CASE` for each `ResponseCode`:

```
SELECT DATE(AcctStartTime) AS `date`
    ,SUM(CASE ResponseCode
        WHEN 200 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS `200`
    ,SUM(CASE ResponseCode
        WHEN 503 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS `503`
    ,SUM(CASE ResponseCode
        WHEN 407 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS `407`
FROM WhateverYourTableIs
GROUP BY `date`
;
```

This should give you the counts you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i was going to do that but it was saying you have to wait for `5 min` then you can accept.. :)

Answer (score 1):

an even better and more concise way to do it is like this

```
SELECT 
    DATE(AcctStartTime) AS `date`,
    SUM(ResponseCode = 200) AS `200`,
    SUM(ResponseCode = 503) AS `503`,
    SUM(ResponseCode = 407) AS `407`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY `date`;
```

this uses the boolean result, when true it returns a 1 that will be summed and 0 when false

Comment: based on this, you equate "better" with "concise" ... i personally equate "better" with "explicit and ANSI as possible". just different techniques to get to the same answer.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea no it actually executes it faster which is why I said its better. the execution time for something this small data wise wouldn't make much of a difference but it would on a large table (I have tested it before)